# GraphQL: No child/nested data available in response when parent is null?

Tags: graphql

I am facing problems with nullable fields when trying to use the data returned when executing my query.

**Schema**

A simplified schema for demonstration purpose:

```
type Query {
    members: [Instrument!]!
}

type Instrument {
    series: SeriesType!
    ...
}

type SeriesType {
    dividendYield: SeriesMethods
    ...
}

type SeriesMethods{
    latest: Float!
    ...
}
```

There is nullable data that is resolved at dividendYield and a typical response I get when executing the query is shown in the following section.

**Typical Response**

[A picture of the query and response can be seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzGvP.png)

**So what is the problem???**

We are using this data to for visuals on a web app. The data is read in as an object such that you are able to access the data by `data.series.dividendYield.latest`. The problem comes in when dividendYield returns null as there is there no longer exists a *latest* field anymore.

For the client side it will always be necessary for the field to be present in the data, even if the parent resolver is null. Is it possible for the resolvers to be setup such that all children fields also return null rather than not appearing in the data response? Any other solutions would also be appreciated.

Comment: post process/normalize fetched data (e.g. using `.map`/`.filter`/reduce/etc in js) before passing to UI/visual [sub-]components

Comment: @xadm can you please expand?

Comment: expand FE details - env?/lang?/client

Comment: @xadm could you provide an example of how any of the mentioned methods may be implemented for my problem? I have been able to set it up on an individual field but it gets complex when attempting to do multiple fields.